# How to creat a C++ Makefile und use it

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw

i try to write a c++ programm on win10 with Mingw but i cant run my Makefile, now i try it a few ours and i think i understand the most of it but it still not work..

```
HashTabelleTest.o: main.o HashTabelle.o
    g++ -o HashTabelleTest main.o HashTabelle.o

main.o: main.cpp HashTabelle.cpp
    g++ -c main.o main.cpp

HashTabelle.o: HashTabelle.cpp HashTabelle.h
    g++ -c HashTabelle.o HashTabelle.cpp HashTabelle.h

clear:
    rm *.o *.exe
```

as admin i use the mingw32-make but all that it says is `Nothing to be Done for 'Makefile.mak'`

i try to edit the the parts to be new but still the same thing

Comment: Sure you used TAB before the rule actions?

Comment: yes, i use notpad++ so it tells me if not

Comment: You should consider using a build toolsuite such as CMake and let it handle the details.

Comment: How do you invoke Make (that is, what command do you use)? There are several faults in this makefile, but it does not mention `Makefile.mak`, so I suspect that this is not the makefile you are using.

Comment: I use  C:\Users\lp_ontour\Desktop\Cpp>mingw32-make Makefile.mak

Comment: If i try to use the command line's directly in the consol it work and i have an Hashtabelletext.exe but the Makefile still dont work..

Answer (score 0):

As I know its a little diffence in win,such as there's no rm but del.But u'd better wirte a **all:** in both system.In linux,I always use below format

```
CC      =   g++
LD      =   g++
CFLAGS  =   -Wall -g -O0
LFLAGS  =   

all:main.elf

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.elf

##########################
main.elf:main.o x.o y.o
    $(LD) -o $@ $^ $(LFLAGS)

%.o:%.cpp
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

Comment: thanks, i will try it with this but it could take some time to understand this

Comment: The most import is that you know:$@ is for target,$^ is all dependecies,$< is for the first dependencies,

Answer (score 0):

I have it:

```
Hashtabelletest: main.o Hashtabelle.o
    g++ -Wall -o Hashtabelletest main.o Hashtabelle.o

main.o: main.cpp Hashtabelle.h
    g++ -Wall -c main.cpp

Hashtabelle.o: Hashtabelle.cpp
    g++ -Wall -c Hashtabelle.cpp
```

1.Problem was that i must copy a libstdc++-6.dll from Mingw\bin into my working folder

2.Thing was that i must type `mingw32-make -f Makefile.mak`, than it workt for my, @all Thanks for support